# Java Printing Odd Symbol When Showing Output of Seperate Process

Tags: java

When I print the output of a separate process I started,  I get the symbol[image]. The code that interests me:

```
in=(char)is.read();
        System.out.println((char)in);
        while (in != -1) {
           outputs[0]=outputs[0]+(char)in;
            in=(char)is.read();
            System.out.println((char)in);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any ideas why my program prints this error? If I don't convert the output into `char` form, I get this:`65535`, which is not an ASCII symbol.

Thanks

Comment: Please include declarations of your variables so we can know their types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Javadoc of `InputStream.read()` (assuming that's the type of `is`, you don't say):

> The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned.

Given that you keep on casting `in` to a `char`, I'm going to guess that `in` is an `int`; assigning a `char` to an `int` means that you are effectively writing `in = (int) (char) is.read()`: `(int) (char) -1` is also 65535.